# C# ClickEvent - Override previous handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a method which run on a click of a button.

- The methods goes to a database and return all products ids(list) wihich match
  a specific keyword.
- It then uses that id to get the corresponding image from the database
  and adds it to a picturebox.

The problem I have is with adding the click evethandler to each picturebox. If I click the search button a second time there is now two eventhndler registered to that picturebox and so on. So when I click on a picurebox sfter pressing the search button twice i will het two messagebox.

Is there a way to drop the previous and only keep the latest eventhandler?

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearPicBoxs();

        if((!txtBoxSearch.Text.Equals("Search...") || !txtBoxSearch.Text.Equals("")) && isLoggedIn)
        {
            //Get Product ids from database which have supplied keyword
            DAOKeyword.SelectKeywords(txtBoxSearch.Text, productIdsList);

            int cnt = 0;

            foreach (int productId in productIdsList)
            {
                ImageDAOImpl DAOIamge = new ImageDAOImpl();

                picPrd = pictureBoxList[cnt];
                picPrd.Text = productId.ToString();
                picPrd.Click += new System.EventHandler((sender1, e1) => picPrd_Click(sender, e, productId));

                picPrd.Image = ByteArrayToImagebyMemoryStream(DAOIamge.SelectImage(productId));
                picPrd.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                picPrd.Refresh();
                cnt++;
            }
            lblLatest_Search.Text = "''" + txtBoxSearch.Text + "''";
            productIdsList.Clear(); 
        }   
        else
        {
            //Select Latest Posted Products
        }
    }



private void picPrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int productId)
        {
            //Use productId to get info about product
            MessageBox.Show(productId.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Why are you adding the eventhandler again? Just do it once.

Comment: add the EventHandler only once (for example in the ctor)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where is the list pictureBoxList is populated, and why you need to assign its items to your controls as long as you set control properties manually.

If you re-instantiate the control each time before assigning the event handler, it should fire it only once 
My suggestion is to replace the below line

```
 picPrd = pictureBoxList[cnt];
```

With the below line

```
 picPrd = new PictureBox();
```